# Install a dotnet tool from local source only

Tags: .net, security, .net-core

I'm making a dotnet tool that will be used in our production servers as a command line application. So I'm installing it from a local source feed as the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-tools-how-to-use) recommends.

```
dotnet tool install --tool-path /usr/bin --add-source path/to/nupkg coolcompany.cooltool
```

The tutorial above also has this warning:

> You gave your package a unique name to make sure that it will only be found in the ./nupkg directory, not on the Nuget.org site.

It seems that in case of a name conflict, `dotnet tool install` picks the package from nuget.org over the local one.

Now, `coolcompany.cooltool` does not actually exist on nuget.org. But somebody could add it later, either by accident or not, and we'd get unexpected code running in production without even knowing it.

Is there a way to force a local source to be used for a particular package? And if not, is it not a security issue? Or am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I haven't tried this, I'd *expect* that using the `--configfile` flag with `dotnet tool install` would work. You'd then specify a config file which *only* includes your local source:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <!-- Don't use any default sources -->
        <clear />
        <!-- Just use the local one -->
        <add key="LocalRepo" value="path/to/nupkg" />
    </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, it works! Running dotnet tools on arm64 linux turned out to be tricky, so we settled for `dotnet path/to/lib.dll` instead, but this definitely answers the question.

Comment: It seems it was foolish for me to try to match with Jon Skeet himself, but at least I tried.

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic haha I appreciated your answer and found it informative, but this one was more specific to the problem. Possibly because I'm risk averse, I feel safer with a "block everything" approach over "block everything according to a schema I 50% understand".

Comment: @NikitaRybak `packageSourceMapping` can be used for regular dependencies, not just tools (this answer breaks regular builds) and resolves security issue you mentioned (anyone on nuget.org can squat your private pkg with malicious one, nuget source order is not deterministic)

Comment: @NikitaRybak btw, source order is [somewhat deterministic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior): NuGet uses sources in order (_of definition in `nuget.config` hierarchy_) in projects using the `packages.config`. Projects using `PackageReference` format, uses local sources first, then sources on network shares, then HTTP sources, regardless of the order in the configuration files. But for `packages.config` first one is usually `nuget.org` defined in global config and for `PackageReference` order of HTTP sources is nondeterministic. ....

Comment: ... So in your case (using `PackageReference` and your source is always local folder) you are ok, but if you publish it your private HTTP feed -- bad things may happen if `packageSourceMapping` is not defined.

Comment: @NikitaRybak I'm curious if this solution still works for you with .NET 8 RC installed?

We do something very similar, although our repo is actually a nuget feed (Artifactory). But still dotnet tool install goes off to nuget.org and doesn't find our tool, and so fails.

This problem is happening on our TeamCity build server and I have to explicitly avoid machines with .NET 8 on to get things to work.

Comment: @IanofOz We're still on dotnet 7, and probably won't migrate to 8 for a while, as we're not primarily a dotnet shop. Hope you'll find a solution!

Comment: Thanks. I did find a solution in the end - turned out to be just waiting for the regression in the .NET 8 SDK to be fixed (which fortunately it has been)

Answer (score 2):

Use [Package Source Mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-source-mapping)

Add `<packageSourceMapping>` section to your `nuget.config`

```xml
<packageSources>
  <add key="MySourceName" value="path/to/nupkgfolder" />
</packageSources>
<packageSourceMapping>
  <!-- key value for <packageSource> should match key values from <packageSources> element -->
  <packageSource key="nuget.org">
    <package pattern="*" />
  </packageSource>
  <packageSource key="MySourceName">
    <package pattern="coolcompany.cooltool" />
  </packageSource>
</packageSourceMapping>
```

Now if package name matches `coolcompany.cooltool`, it will always be fetched from `MySourceName` nuget feed, but still allows all other packages to be fetched from nuget.org.